# Only 'npm install' in GitLab CI when package.json has been updated

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, npm-install, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab CI for a project and the first step of the process is `npm install`. I cache `node_modules` for quicker runs of the same job later on, and also define them as build artifacts in order to use them in later stages. However, even though I cache `node_modules` and it's up-to-date, calling `npm install` each time the `install_packages` job is run takes a long time, since the command goes through all of `package.json` and checks for updates of packages and such (I assume).

Is there any way to **only** run `npm install` in the `install_packages` job depending on some condition? More specifically (what I think would be the best solution), whether or not `package.json` has been changed since last build?

Below is the relevant part of my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: node:6.9.1

stages:
  - install
  - prepare
  - deploy

install_packages:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm prune
    - npm install
  cache:
    key: ${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  only:
    - master
    - develop

build_and_test:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    #do_stuff...

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  #do_stuff...

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  #do_stuff...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the `only:changes` flag [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges)

The job will be:

```
install_packages:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm prune
    - npm install
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - develop
    changes:
      - package.json
```

Another point is: You set the cache the right way?
Read this:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/

Answer (score 1):

Are you npm installing with the --cache option? I've heard this problem with a few Gitlab CI runners that people have and this is the solution most the time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That sounds like something that would do the trick, but could you specify further? What exactly should the command be? `npm install --cache` does not exist to my knowledge. Or are you talking about the [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache) cli command? I'm not sure how I would go about using that in GitLab CI.

Comment: @JorJor this is what I found for GitLab CI intergration. Hope it helps